# Преобразование объекта класса к list и dict

Tags: python, ооп, классы, list, словари

Захотелось мне поизучать графы, и вот написал я простой класс `Graph`, в нём есть переменная g_map, которая хранит сам граф в виде словаря примерно так:

```py
class Graph:
    g_map = dict()
    ...
    Не очень важно сейчас
    ...
    def __init__(self, g):
        self.g_map = g

a = Graph({'a': {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c':12, 'd': 31, 'e': 19},
          'b': {'a': 1, 'b': 32, 'c':2, 'd': 31, 'e': 19},
          'c': {'a': 12, 'b': 2, 'c':0, 'd': 12, 'e': 19},
          'd': {'a': 31, 'b': 31, 'c':12, 'd': 0, 'e': 31},
          'e': {'a': 19, 'b': 19, 'c':19, 'd': 31, 'e': 0}
          })
```

таким образом, я могу хранить вершины по названиям, и называть их как угодно

(здесь в словаре по каждому ключу (название вершины) хранится словарь где по каждому ключу(опять же название вершины) хранится значение длины дороги до той вершины )

я хочу, чтоб я мог обращатся к графу вот так:

```py
print(a['a']['c'])

# вернет 12
```

для этого в классе `Graph` я реализовал методы:

```
def __getitem__(self, item):
    else:
        return self.g_map[item]

def __setitem__(self, key,  value):
    self.g_map[key] = value

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.g)
```

этот код прекрасно работает, но я хочу иметь возможность такого: `dict(a)` который бы возвращал по сути `g_map`

и `list(a)` который бы работал так же как `list(dict(какой-то словарь))` то есть возвращал список всех ключей. то есть чтобы list(a) в данном примере возвращал `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']`

я думал для этого есть методы типа `__list__`, `__dict__`, но как оказалось их нет, и я прошу вашей помощи:

Как реализовать нужное мне поведение?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для того чтобы cрабатывал метод dict и list на вашем объекте вам необходимо реализовать методы `__iter__`, `__getitem__` и `keys`. И в простом варианте это можно сделать так:

```
class A():

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.a.__iter__()

    def __getitem__(self, *args):
        return self.a.__getitem__(*args)

    def keys(self):
        return self.a.keys()

obj = A({"x": 1, "y": 2, "z": 3})

print(dict(obj))

print(list(obj))
```

Можно попробовать сделать тоже самое при помощи наследования.